# JupyterLab 3.0.4 Build error. [webpack-cli] [31mTypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation

Tags: jupyter, webclient, jupyter-lab

There is an error when I try to run jupyter lab build. I tried unistalling jupyterlab and reinstalling it, I also tried that approach with the whole anaconda. I am running it on Windows 10. This is the error:

```
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 3.0.4
[LabBuildApp] Building in c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
Build failed.
Troubleshooting: If the build failed due to an out-of-memory error, you
may be able to fix it by disabling the `dev_build` and/or `minimize` options.

If you are building via the `jupyter lab build` command, you can disable
these options like so:

jupyter lab build --dev-build=False --minimize=False

You can also disable these options for all JupyterLab builds by adding these
lines to a Jupyter config file named `jupyter_config.py`:

c.LabBuildApp.minimize = False
c.LabBuildApp.dev_build = False

If you don't already have a `jupyter_config.py` file, you can create one by
adding a blank file of that name to any of the Jupyter config directories.
The config directories can be listed by running:

jupyter --paths

Explanation:

- `dev-build`: This option controls whether a `dev` or a more streamlined
`production` build is used. This option will default to `False` (i.e., the
`production` build) for most users. However, if you have any labextensions
installed from local files, this option will instead default to `True`.
Explicitly setting `dev-build` to `False` will ensure that the `production`
build is used in all circumstances.

- `minimize`: This option controls whether your JS bundle is minified
during the Webpack build, which helps to improve JupyterLab's overall
performance. However, the minifier plugin used by Webpack is very memory
intensive, so turning it off may help the build finish successfully in
low-memory environments.

An error occured.
RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\acrul\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-9xkqhcqu.log
```

And the log file. I assume the error is here:
[webpack-cli] [31mTypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
at Function.getCompilationHooks (c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:119:10)

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v14.15.4

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
[LabBuildApp] > node c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "@jupyterlab/extensionmanager > react-paginate@6.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/json-extension > react-highlighter@0.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/json-extension > react-json-tree@0.12.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/json-extension > react-json-tree@0.12.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.3.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/ui-components > @blueprintjs/core > react-popper@1.3.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/ui-components > @blueprintjs/core > react-popper > create-react-context@0.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@jupyterlab/vdom > @nteract/transform-vdom@4.0.16-alpha.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^16.3.2".
warning " > @lumino/coreutils@1.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "crypto@1.0.1".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 5.77s.

[LabBuildApp] > node c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\.bin\yarn-deduplicate -s fewer --fail
Done in 0.45s.

[LabBuildApp] > node c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js run build:prod:minimize
[LabBuildApp] yarn run v1.21.1
$ webpack --config webpack.prod.minimize.config.js
[webpack-cli] [31mTypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of Compilation
    at Function.getCompilationHooks (c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptModulesPlugin.js:119:10)
    at c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:566:67
    at _next35 (eval at create (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:40:1)
    at _next13 (eval at create (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:97:1)
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:127:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:988:26)
    at c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1030:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (c:\Users\acrul\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)[39m
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab failed to build
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 168, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 164, in start
    build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp]   File "c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 463, in build
    return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp]   File "c:\users\acrul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 675, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

Comment: You may have two two or more webpack installations, or a wrong webpack version installed. https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/1451. You should include information on why and how you run the build process (as it is not normally required for installation).

Comment: I definitely do have have an up to date web pack install on my machine.  Clearly this can't be tied to a global webpack dependency or it could break other builds.  What's the work around?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how i solved it, but i repeatedly run these as admin

```
jupyter lab clean
jupyter lab clean --all
pip uninstall jupyterlab
pip install jupyterlab
```

Then also started the `jupyter lab` server from another folder than usual.